# Faster version of find for sorted vectors (MATLAB)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting, optimization

I have code of the following kind in MATLAB:

```
indices = find([1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7] == 3)
```

This returns 4,5,6 - the indices of elements in the array equal to 3. Now. my code does this sort of thing with very long vectors. The vectors are *always sorted*.

Therefore, I would like a function which replaces the O(n) complexity of find with O(log n), at the expense that the array has to be sorted.

I am aware of ismember, but for what I know it does not return the indices of all items, just the last one (I need all of them).

For reasons of portability, I need the solution to be MATLAB-only (no compiled mex files etc.)

Comment: Not sure if it is possible in MATLAB, but if you implement your own binary search, that should do it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a fast implementation using binary search. This file is also available on [github](https://github.com/danielroeske/danielsmatlabtools/blob/master/matlab/data/findinsorted.m)

```
function [b,c]=findInSorted(x,range)
%findInSorted fast binary search replacement for ismember(A,B) for the
%special case where the first input argument is sorted.
%   
%   [a,b] = findInSorted(x,s) returns the range which is equal to s. 
%   r=a:b and r=find(x == s) produce the same result   
%  
%   [a,b] = findInSorted(x,[from,to]) returns the range which is between from and to
%   r=a:b and r=find(x >= from & x <= to) return the same result
%
%   For any sorted list x you can replace
%   [lia] = ismember(x,from:to)
%   with
%   [a,b] = findInSorted(x,[from,to])
%   lia=a:b
%
%   Examples:
%
%       x  = 1:99
%       s  = 42
%       r1 = find(x == s)
%       [a,b] = myFind(x,s)
%       r2 = a:b
%       %r1 and r2 are equal
%
%   See also FIND, ISMEMBER.
%
% Author Daniel Roeske <danielroeske.de>

A=range(1);
B=range(end);
a=1;
b=numel(x);
c=1;
d=numel(x);
if A<=x(1)
   b=a;
end
if B>=x(end)
    c=d;
end
while (a+1<b)
    lw=(floor((a+b)/2));
    if (x(lw)<A)
        a=lw;
    else
        b=lw;
    end
end
while (c+1<d)
    lw=(floor((c+d)/2));
    if (x(lw)<=B)
        c=lw;
    else
        d=lw;
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Maybe this code could be further improved. For most iterations a is equal to c and b is equal to d.

Comment: Don't think it can get any faster!  This is your standard binary search algorithm.  The worst case complexity is `O(log n)` which is as fast as you can get it!  BTW nice job :)

Comment: @rayryeng: You are right, `O(log n)` is the lower boundary. I thought it would be possible to increase the speed by ~30%, but I was wrong. I tried it and the best I achieved was the same speed.

Comment: There are some bugs with this answer -- see DrGar's answer, which fixes these.

Comment: @carl: Can you give me an example of a case when the result would not be correct? The only problem that I found is that the lower and upper bound will be reversed if requested range is not included in the list. For example, `myFind2([1:3 7:10], 4, 6)` would produce `4` and `3` instead of `3` and `4`.

Answer (score 15):

Daniel's approach is clever and his myFind2 function is definitely fast, but there are errors/bugs that occur near the boundary conditions or in the case that the upper and lower bounds produce a range outside the set passed in.

Additionally, as he noted in his comment on his answer, his implementation had some inefficiencies that could be improved. I implemented an improved version of his code, which runs faster, while also correctly handling boundary conditions. Furthermore, this code includes more comments to explain what is happening. I hope this helps someone the way Daniel's code helped me here!

```matlab
function [lower_index,upper_index] = myFindDrGar(x,LowerBound,UpperBound)
% fast O(log2(N)) computation of the range of indices of x that satify the
% upper and lower bound values using the fact that the x vector is sorted
% from low to high values. Computation is done via a binary search.
%
% Input:
%
% x-            A vector of sorted values from low to high.       
%
% LowerBound-   Lower boundary on the values of x in the search
%
% UpperBound-   Upper boundary on the values of x in the search
%
% Output:
%
% lower_index-  The smallest index such that
%               LowerBound<=x(index)<=UpperBound
%
% upper_index-  The largest index such that
%               LowerBound<=x(index)<=UpperBound

if LowerBound>x(end) || UpperBound<x(1) || UpperBound<LowerBound
    % no indices satify bounding conditions
    lower_index = [];
    upper_index = [];
    return;
end

lower_index_a=1;
lower_index_b=length(x); % x(lower_index_b) will always satisfy lowerbound
upper_index_a=1;         % x(upper_index_a) will always satisfy upperbound
upper_index_b=length(x);

%
% The following loop increases _a and decreases _b until they differ 
% by at most 1. Because one of these index variables always satisfies the 
% appropriate bound, this means the loop will terminate with either 
% lower_index_a or lower_index_b having the minimum possible index that 
% satifies the lower bound, and either upper_index_a or upper_index_b 
% having the largest possible index that satisfies the upper bound. 
%
while (lower_index_a+1<lower_index_b) || (upper_index_a+1<upper_index_b)

    lw=floor((lower_index_a+lower_index_b)/2); % split the upper index

    if x(lw) >= LowerBound
        lower_index_b=lw; % decrease lower_index_b (whose x value remains \geq to lower bound)   
    else
        lower_index_a=lw; % increase lower_index_a (whose x value remains less than lower bound)
        if (lw>upper_index_a) && (lw<upper_index_b)
            upper_index_a=lw;% increase upper_index_a (whose x value remains less than lower bound and thus upper bound)
        end
    end

    up=ceil((upper_index_a+upper_index_b)/2);% split the lower index
    if x(up) <= UpperBound
        upper_index_a=up; % increase upper_index_a (whose x value remains \leq to upper bound) 
    else
        upper_index_b=up; % decrease upper_index_b
        if (up<lower_index_b) && (up>lower_index_a)
            lower_index_b=up;%decrease lower_index_b (whose x value remains greater than upper bound and thus lower bound)
        end
    end
end

if x(lower_index_a)>=LowerBound
    lower_index = lower_index_a;
else
    lower_index = lower_index_b;
end
if x(upper_index_b)<=UpperBound
    upper_index = upper_index_b;
else
    upper_index = upper_index_a;
end
```

Note that the improved version of Daniels searchFor function is now simply:

```matlab
function [lower_index,upper_index] = mySearchForDrGar(x,value)

[lower_index,upper_index] = myFindDrGar(x,value,value);
```

EDIT many years later: there was an error in the last two if/else blocks, fixed it.

Comment: Note that it would not return inclusive indices (i.e. LowerBound<=x(index)<=UpperBound). This can be verified by `[li, ui] = mySearchForDrGar(1:10, 5, 6)`

Comment: I know this is old but for other readers, this function gives [lower_index-1, upper_index+1] in my tests.

Comment: @JeanMercat There was a small error in the last two if/else blocks, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 11):

`ismember` will give you all the indexes if you look at the first output:

```
>> x = [1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7];
>> [tf,loc]=ismember(x,3);
>> inds = find(tf)
```

inds =

```
 4     5     6
```

You just need to use the right order of inputs.

Note that there is a helper function used by `ismember` that you can call directly:

```
% ISMEMBC  - S must be sorted - Returns logical vector indicating which 
% elements of A occur in S

tf = ismembc(x,3);
inds = find(tf);
```

Using `ismembc` will save computation time since `ismember` calls `issorted` first, but this will omit the check.

Note that newer versions of matlab have a builtin called by `builtin('_ismemberoneoutput',a,b)` with the same functionality.

---

Since the above applications of `ismember`, etc. are somewhat backwards (searching for each element of `x` in the second argument rather than the other way around), the code is much slower than necessary.  As the OP points out, it is unfortunate that `[~,loc]=ismember(3,x)` only provides the location of the first occurrence of 3 in `x`, rather than all.  However, if you have a recent version of MATLAB (R2012b+, I think), you can use yet more undocumented builtin functions to get the first an last indexes! These are `ismembc2` and `builtin('_ismemberfirst',searchfor,x)`:

```
firstInd = builtin('_ismemberfirst',searchfor,x);  % find first occurrence
lastInd = ismembc2(searchfor,x);                   % find last occurrence
% lastInd = ismembc2(searchfor,x(firstInd:end))+firstInd-1; % slower
inds = firstInd:lastInd;
```

Still slower than Daniel R.'s great MATLAB code, but there it is (`rntmX` added to randomatlabuser's benchmark) just for fun:

```
mean([rntm1 rntm2 rntm3 rntmX])    
ans =
   0.559204323050486   0.263756852283128   0.000017989974213   0.000153682125682
```

Here are the bits of documentation for these functions inside `ismember.m`:

```
% ISMEMBC2 - S must be sorted - Returns a vector of the locations of
% the elements of A occurring in S.  If multiple instances occur,
% the last occurrence is returned

% ISMEMBERFIRST(A,B) - B must be sorted - Returns a vector of the
% locations of the elements of A occurring in B.  If multiple
% instances occur, the first occurence is returned.
```

There is actually reference to an `ISMEMBERLAST` builtin, but it doesn't seem to exist (yet?).

Comment: @chappjc: rntmX is the execution time of `_ismemberfirst`? It's not too bad - maybe it is slowed down by internal checks?

Comment: @randomatlabuser Yes, `rntmX` is the execution of the three lines of code including `_ismemberfirst` and `ismembc2`.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer - I am just comparing the running time of the three solutions suggested by chappjc and Daniel R.

```
N = 5e7;    % length of vector
p = 0.99;    % probability
KK = 100;    % number of instances
rntm1 = zeros(KK, 1);    % runtime with ismember
rntm2 = zeros(KK, 1);    % runtime with ismembc
rntm3 = zeros(KK, 1);    % runtime with Daniel's function
for kk = 1:KK
    x = cumsum(rand(N, 1) > p);
    searchfor = x(ceil(4*N/5));

    tic
    [tf,loc]=ismember(x, searchfor);
    inds1 = find(tf);
    rntm1(kk) = toc;

    tic
    tf = ismembc(x, searchfor);
    inds2 = find(tf);
    rntm2(kk) = toc;

    tic
    a=1;
    b=numel(x);
    c=1;
    d=numel(x);
    while (a+1<b||c+1<d)
        lw=(floor((a+b)/2));
        if (x(lw)<searchfor)
            a=lw;
        else
            b=lw;
        end
        lw=(floor((c+d)/2));
        if (x(lw)<=searchfor)
            c=lw;
        else
            d=lw;
        end
    end
    inds3 = (b:c)';
    rntm3(kk) = toc;

end
```

Daniel's binary search is very fast.

```
% Mean of running time
mean([rntm1 rntm2 rntm3])
% 0.631132275892504   0.295233981447746   0.000400786666188

% Percentiles of running time
prctile([rntm1 rntm2 rntm3], [0 25 50 75 100])
% 0.410663611685559   0.175298784336465   0.000012828868032
% 0.429120717937665   0.185935198821797   0.000014539383770
% 0.582281366154709   0.268931132925888   0.000019243302048
% 0.775917520641649   0.385297304740352   0.000026940622867
% 1.063753914942895   0.592429428396956   0.037773746662356
```

Comment: Very interesting! With the JIT compiler for the MATLAB solution and external function call overhead for the C function, we have a surprising result.  Props to Daniel. How does the other `builtin` compare?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the builtin. Daniel's solution requires at most `ceil(log2(N))` loops: when `N = 5e7` the loops are just 26 at most.

Comment: I guess [chappjc's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20167085/1143274) means that in `rntm2`, the `find(tf)` call takes up almost all of the time, while the `ismembc(..)` call itself is very quick.

Comment: Just realized my function is that fast that you notice the difference between a function call and inlining my code.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a function like this. Thanks for the post @Daniel!

I worked a little with it because I needed to find several indexes in the same array. I wanted to avoid the overhead of `arrayfun` (or the like) or calling the function multiple times. So you can pass a bunch of values in `range` and you will get the indexes in the array.

```
function idx = findInSorted(x,range)
% Author Dídac Rodríguez Arbonès (May 2018)
% Based on Daniel Roeske's solution:
%   Daniel Roeske <danielroeske.de>
%   https://github.com/danielroeske/danielsmatlabtools/blob/master/matlab/data/findinsorted.m

    range = sort(range);
    idx = nan(size(range));
    for i=1:numel(range)
        idx(i) = aux(x, range(i));
    end
end

function b = aux(x, lim)
    a=1;
    b=numel(x);
    if lim<=x(1)
       b=a;
    end
    if lim>=x(end)
       a=b;
    end

    while (a+1<b)
        lw=(floor((a+b)/2));
        if (x(lw)<lim)
            a=lw;
        else
            b=lw;
        end
    end
end
```

I guess you can use a `parfor` or `arrayfun` instead. I have not tested myself at what size of `range` it pays off, though.

Another possible improvement would be to use the previous found indexes (if `range` is sorted) to decrease the search space. I am skeptical of its potential to save CPU because of the `O(log n)` runtime.

---

The final function ended up running slightly faster. I used @randomatlabuser 's framework for that:

```
N = 5e6;    % length of vector
p = 0.99;    % probability
KK = 100;    % number of instances
rntm1 = zeros(KK, 1);    % runtime with ismember
rntm2 = zeros(KK, 1);    % runtime with ismembc
rntm3 = zeros(KK, 1);    % runtime with Daniel's function
for kk = 1:KK
    x = cumsum(rand(N, 1) > p);
    searchfor = x(ceil(4*N/5));

    tic
    range = sort(searchfor);
    idx = nan(size(range));
    for i=1:numel(range)
        idx(i) = aux(x, range(i));
    end

    rntm1(kk) = toc;

    tic
    a=1;
    b=numel(x);
    c=1;
    d=numel(x);
    while (a+1<b||c+1<d)
        lw=(floor((a+b)/2));
        if (x(lw)<searchfor)
            a=lw;
        else
            b=lw;
        end
        lw=(floor((c+d)/2));
        if (x(lw)<=searchfor)
            c=lw;
        else
            d=lw;
        end
    end
    inds3 = (b:c)';
    rntm2(kk) = toc;

end

%%

function b = aux(x, lim)

a=1;
b=numel(x);
if lim<=x(1)
   b=a;
end
if lim>=x(end)
   a=b;
end

while (a+1<b)
    lw=(floor((a+b)/2));
    if (x(lw)<lim)
        a=lw;
    else
        b=lw;
    end
end

end
```

It is not a big improvement, but it helps because I need to run several thousand searches.

```
% Mean of running time
mean([rntm1 rntm2])
% 9.9624e-05  5.6303e-05

% Percentiles of running time
prctile([rntm1 rntm2], [0 25 50 75 100])
% 3.0435e-05  1.0524e-05
% 3.4133e-05  1.2231e-05
% 3.7262e-05  1.3369e-05
% 3.9111e-05  1.4507e-05
%  0.0027426   0.0020301
```

I hope this can help somebody.

---

**EDIT**

If there is a significant chance of having exact matches, it pays off to use the very fast built-in `ismember` before calling the function:

```
[found, idx] = ismember(range, x);
idx(~found) = arrayfun(@(r) aux(x, r), range(~found));
```