# MATLAB-ish way to keep common entry rows between two cell arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab

As a newbie in MATLAB, I find myself always going for the C++-like looping instead of exploiting the matrix-based operations. I encounter another problem today.

Suppose I have two two-column tables (cell arrays), first column being user ID and second column being the corresponding values. However, they are of different sizes in the row. i.e.

```
Table 1

1 2.56
2 7.4
3 7.7
...
100 83.4

Table 2

1 7.1
3 1.4
4 4.4
...
76 7.2
```

Despite the differen row sizes, the two tables actually share some common ID. **Now I wish to form a new cell array of size `Nx3`, where `N` is the number of the common IDs and 1st and 2nd columns are the values from table 1 and table 2**, respectively. i.e.

```
New Table

1 2.56 7.1
3 7.7 1.4
...
```

Again, I can use a loop to do it, but I really wish to learn a MATLAB-ish way of doing this.

Comment: Were you happy with any of the answers. Personally I believe `ismember` is the most "MATLAB-ish" solution. ;) And I showed it to be faster with sorted data.

Comment: @chappjc Yes, I agree. That is awesome! Thanks a lot for the detailed analysis! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), which is very efficient with sorted inputs, as the indexes are in this case:

```
A = [1 2.56;
     2  7.4;
     3  7.7];
B = [1  7.1;
     3  1.4;
     4  4.4];

[tf,locb] = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1))
```

You only need the two outputs this way: `tf` is a map of rows in `A` that also exist in `B`, `locb` is the location in `B` for each element in `A` (i.e. same length as `A`, zero where there is no match).

As such, a common idiom is to index `locb` with `tf`:

```
>> C = [A(tf,:) B(locb(tf),2:end)]
C =
    1.0000    2.5600    7.1000
    3.0000    7.7000    1.4000
```

---

Consider the speed difference between `ismember` and `intersect` when the inputs are sorted. Small-ish data:

```
N = 1e5;  A = [(1:N).' rand(N,1)];  B = [(1:N).' rand(N,1)];


>> tic; [tf,locb] = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.013419 seconds.
>> tic; [C, ia, ib] = intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.050618 seconds.
```

Although `ismember` is several times faster, there is no big advantage for small data. However, with large sorted data sets, use `ismember`:

```
N = 1e7;  A = [(1:N).' rand(N,1)];  B = [(1:N).' rand(N,1)];

>> tic; [tf,locb] = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.892977 seconds.
>> tic; [C, ia, ib] = intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1)); toc
Elapsed time is 5.925537 seconds.
```

NOTE: If you want to really take advantage of *a priori* knowledge of sorted inputs, there is an [undocumented function called `ismembc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167085/2778484) that skips a call to `issorted`, making it even faster than `ismember`. See also [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function/).

Answer (score 2):

I personally think using loop is fine. How about using `intersect`?

```
A = [1 2.56;2 7.4;3 7.7];
B = [1 7.1; 3 1.4;4 4.4];

[C, ia, ib] = intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1));

D = [A(ia,:), B(ib,2:end)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved neatly with the very versatile [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) function:

```
C1 = {1 2.56; 2 7.4; 3 7.7; 100 83.4};
C2 = {1 7.1; 3 1.4; 4 4.4; 76 7.2}; %// example data. Two-column cell arrays

comp = bsxfun(@eq, [C1{:,1}], [C2{:,1}].'); %'// test all pairs for equality
ind1 = any(comp,1); %// values of first col of C1 that coincide with some in C2
ind2 = any(comp,2); %// values of first col of C2 that coincide with some in C1
result = horzcat(C1(ind1,1), C1(ind1,2), C2(ind2,2)); %// build result
```

Note that

- `[C1{:,1}]` is used to turn the first column of the cell array `C1` into a (numeric) row  vector. [Here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)'s why this works.
- The second argument to [`any`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/any.html) specifies which dimension it operates along.
- `ind1` and `ind2` are [logical indices](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/).

Also, numeric arrays (matrices) in Matlab are more efficient than cell arrays. If all the cells in your cell array contain a single number, as in your case, consider using a numeric array instead. Cell arrays are useful when each cell must contain objects of different size or of different type (for example if one column contains numbers and another column contains strings).

If you use numeric arrays, the code also becomes slightly simpler in this case:

```
C1 = [1 2.56; 2 7.4; 3 7.7; 100 83.4];
C2 = [1 7.1; 3 1.4; 4 4.4; 76 7.2]; %// example data. Two-column matrices

comp = bsxfun(@eq, C1(:,1).', C2(:,1)); %'// test all pairs for equality
ind1 = any(comp,1); %// values of first col of C1 that coincide with some in C2
ind2 = any(comp,2); %// values of first col of C2 that coincide with some in C1
result = [C1(ind1,1) C1(ind1,2) C2(ind2,2)]; %// build result
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, I think @ysakamto's answer is best.  However, if you're using a newer version of Matlab (last year?), they added a `table` datatype which supports SQL-type operations such as `join`.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/join.html

Comment: `ismember` is very efficient with sorted inputs, which they are in this case.

Comment: That's very possible, only @yskamto's answer was posted when I started writing mine.  Interesting the number of useful solutions to this problem.  Perhaps the OP will implement them all on his data and time them for us?

Comment: I added a performance comparison to my answer. `ismember` is several times faster, and the difference becomes large as the data gets big.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I actually meant the original asker, didn't mean to suggest more work for you, but seeing performance data on alternate solutions is always extremely helpful.  Thanks for posting it.

Comment: I know.  I'm here for the fun after all, not the good pay!  ;)