# How to give the matlab "find" function a hint that the list is sorted?

Tags: matlab

I want to use `find` function in matlab to find the index of first value that is bigger than a number `C`. the list is too long and it takes a lot of time to execute. But the values are actually sorted in increasing manner. How can I take advantage of that feature of data in matlab?

Comment: [A fast implementation of find to search for intervals can be found in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20167257/2732801), you may adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Just realized you don't need to adapt the code. You can directly call `[a,a]=myFind(x,[C,C])` which will return you the position of the first and last number C. You may improve the performance by roughly a factor of 2 skipping the search for the last element, but I expect that it's not worth the coding effort.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it works great.

Answer (score 2):

```
find(Data>C,1,'first')
```

set the `'first'` switch in [`find`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html). This will ensure that as soon as it finds the first element satisfying the criterion it will stop looking.

Comment: Thanks Adriaan, Is there any solution that actually get use the sorted nature of data? some sort of embedded binary search,etc.

Comment: This uses the fact that it's sorted, as it stops as soon as the first match is found.

Comment: @Adriaan: `find` does not know / assume that the vector is sorted, thus it searches through every element until the number is found, potentially touching every element. Binary search (see answer I linked) can be much faster.