# Fastest way of finding the only index of vector b where array A(i,j) == b

Tags: matlab, performance, find

I have 2 big arrays `A` and `b`:

`A`: 10.000++ rows, 4 columns, not unique integers
`b`: vector with 500.000++ elements, unique integers

Due to the uniqueness of the values of `b`, I need to find the only index of `b`, where `A(i,j) == b`.

What I started with is

```
[rows,columns] = size(A);
B = zeros(rows,columns);
for i = 1 : rows
    for j = 1 : columns
        B(i,j) = find(A(i,j)==b,1);
    end
end
```

This takes approx **5.5 seconds** to compute, which is way to long, since `A` and `b` can be significantly bigger... That in mind I tried to speed up the code by using logical indexing and reducing the for-loops

```
[rows,columns] = size(A);
B = zeros(rows,columns);
for idx = 1 : numel(b)
    B(A==b(idx)) = idx;
end
```

Sadly this takes even longer: **21 seconds**

I even tried to do use `bsxfun`

```
for i = 1 : columns
   [I,J] = find(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,i),b))
    ... stitch B together ...
end
```

but with a bigger arrays the maximum array size is quickly exceeded (102,9GB...).

Can you help me find a faster solution to this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I extended `find(A(i,j)==b`**`,1`**`)`, which speeds up the algorithm by factor 2! Thank you, but overall still too slow... ;)

Comment: Are both `A` and `b` dense matrices? Can you use sparse matrices?

Comment: Is every value in `A` guaranteed to be in `b`?

Comment: @gnovice yes they are! The solution of Cris Lugeno is the one I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) is the right tool for this:

```
[~,B] = ismember(A,b);
```

Test code:

```
function so
  A = rand(1000,4);
  b = unique([A(:);rand(2000,1)]);

  B1 = op1(A,b);
  B2 = op2(A,b);
  isequal(B1,B2)

  tic;op1(A,b);op1(A,b);op1(A,b);op1(A,b);toc
  tic;op2(A,b);op2(A,b);op2(A,b);op2(A,b);toc
end

function B = op1(A,b)
  B = zeros(size(A));
  for i = 1:numel(A)
    B(i) = find(A(i)==b,1);
  end
end

function B = op2(A,b)
  [~,B] = ismember(A,b);
end
```

I ran this on Octave, which is not as fast with loops as MATLAB. It also doesn't have the `timeit` function, hence the crappy timing using `tic`/`toc` (sorry for that). In Octave, `op2` is more than 100 times faster than `op1`. Timings will be different in MATLAB, but `ismember` should still be the fastest option. (Note I also replaced your double loop with a single loop, this is the same but simpler and probably faster.)

If you want to repeatedly do the search in `b`, it is worthwhile to sort `b` first, and implement your own binary search. This will avoid the checks and sorting that `ismember` does. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166847/faster-version-of-find-for-sorted-vectors-matlab).

Comment: It should be noted that the use of [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) comes with the obligatory floating point comparison caveat. [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) was introduced in R2015a to mitigate these types of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have positive integers you can use array indexing:

```
mm = max(max(A(:)),max(b(:)));
idxs = sparse(b,1,1:numel(b),mm,1);
result = full(idxs(A));
```

If the range of values is small you can use dense matrix instead of sparse matrix:

```
mm = max(max(A(:)),max(b(:)));
idx = zeros(mm,1);
idx(b)=1:numel(b);
result = idx(A);
```